# Trying to deploy on Vercel and I get this ""is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 204"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I hope you are well. I'm working on a full-stack application. When I run my app on localhost, it works fine. I deployed the server on Vercel as well as the front end. I have a registration and login form, but when I click on the submit button it throws an error in the browser console.

I have been trying to fix it for two days now. It might be something small that I cannot see. I would appreciate your help.

Error:
[image]

Register Route,

```
  const { firstName, username, age, email, password} = req.body;
  console.log("Registration user input:", firstName, username, age, email, password);

  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username });

    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Username already taken. Please try a different one." });
    }
    
    const existingEmail = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (existingEmail) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email already taken. Please try a different one." });
    }

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const newUser = new User({firstName,username,age,email,password: hashedPassword,});
  
    await newUser.save();
  
    const token = jwt.sign(
      { id: newUser._id, username: newUser.username },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET!,
      { expiresIn: "1h" }
    );
  
    res.status(201).json({ message: "User created successfully", token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
});
```

Frontend:

```
    event.preventDefault();
    setErrorMessage("");
  
    if (!firstName || firstName.length <= 1) {
      setErrorMessage("First name is required and should be longer than 1 character.");
    } else if (!username || username.length <= 4) {
      setErrorMessage("Username is required and should be longer than 4 characters.");
    } else if (!age || Number(age) <= 12) {
      setErrorMessage("Age is required and should be more than 12.");
    } else if (!email || !email.includes("@")) {
      setErrorMessage("A valid email is required.");
    } else if (!password || !/[!@#$%^&*]/.test(password) || password.length <= 8) {
      setErrorMessage("Password is required, should be longer than 8 characters, and contain at least one special character.");
    } else if (password !== passwordConfirmation) {
      setErrorMessage("Password confirmation does not match the password.");
    } else {
      try {
        //const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/register", {method: "POST", mode: "cors", headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },body: JSON.stringify({ firstName, username, age, email, password })});
        const response = await fetch("https://---------.vercel.app/api/register", { method: "POST", headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },body: JSON.stringify({ firstName, username, age, email, password })});
        if (response.ok) {
          console.log("User registered successfully");
          localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true");
          navigate("/intro");
        } else {
          const data = await response.json();
          setErrorMessage(data.message || "Failed to register user"); 
          console.error("Failed to register user");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error);
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to refer to domain2 from domain1. The issue is that the browser, due to security measures restricts this and throws a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS) error instead.

In order to fix this issue, your API will need to send response headers to your request (I mean Access-Control-Allow-Origin most importantly) so your browser will know that this behavior is accepted by your API and there is no reason to panic. Read about these headers:

- [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)
- [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials)
- [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)
- [Access-Control-Allow-Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods)
- [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)
- [Access-Control-Max-Age](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age)
- [Access-Control-Request-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Headers)
- [Access-Control-Request-Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Method)
- [Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin)
- [Timing-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Timing-Allow-Origin)